# Where is SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I just upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 Professional to Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. With Professional, I had access to the SQL Server Object Explorer, from under the View drop-down menu. But now, with Ultimate, I no longer have a menu entry for SQL Server Object Explorer. It's supposedly integrated with all versions of VS 2013. I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate installed on a different computer and it has the menu item available.

Does anybody know why SQL Server Object Explorer might not be available? I'm on Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+\, Ctrl+S combination?

Comment: It says it's not a command.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, you can connect to a SQL Server database from either SQL Server Object Explorer or the Data Connections node in Server Explorer. SQL Server Object Explorer provides a view that is like SQL Server Management Studio. To open this explorer from the menu bar, choose View, SQL Server Object Explorer. For more information, see Connected Database Development. [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6sa01t4.aspx)  **THE** Google says nothing?

Comment: http://www.sqlserver.co.uk/index.php/category/sql-server-data-tools/
search for: Connected development in SSDT versus SSMS

Comment: Nothing on here has seemed to help. A lot of those downloads and links are for Visual Studio 2012, also. On my laptop, I installed VS 2013 Ultimate on a fresh Windows 8.1 64-bit install, and the SQL Server Object Explorer is available. So, I know I don't need any additional downloads or services. For some reason on my main PC that option is just not available, though.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Do you have SSDT installed as well? Because someone else has reported installing both SSDT and VS2013 can end with broken components :-( But that was in September and they said it was fixed by another build. I've installed the latest January build and it seems to have broken it for me - no SQL menu in VS2013 and no SSOX.

Comment: Cody, I just updated this question with the answer that fixed it for me. If you had previous versions of VS installed, try doing what I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to actually go into Control Panel and manually uninstall everything that Visual Studio installed - primarily all SQL-related items, etc.

In my situation, I upgraded from Visual Studio 2012, then to Visual Studio 2013 Professional and finally to Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate over the course of several months. This upgrade path apparently caused Visual Studio 2013 to fail to load the SQL Server Object Explorer menu item because I assume there were version conflicts or something with the SQL-related applications that Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 Pro had installed.

Uninstalling everything and the re-installing VS 2013 Ultimated fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

i also hate this problem. But it has an easy solution: Run your Visual Studio 2013 installer > select MODIFY > check SQL Server Data Tools option. If you don't have an installer, you can visit this page to download SQL Server Data Tools.